# sumproduct using different criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the above excel table and i would like to calculate the total per company per departament per year. I used:
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$9=A12),--($B$2:$B$9=B12)*$C$2:$F$9)
dosen`t seems to work.

```
       A            B            C             D           E           F                   
1    COMPANY      DEPART.     QUARTER 1     QUARTER 2    QUARTER 3   QUARTER 4       
2    AB           PRO          123           223         3354        556                
3    CD           PIV          222           235         223         568                
4    CD           PRO          236           254         184         223            
5    AB           STA          254           221         96          265             
6    EF           PIV          254           112         485         256              
7    CD           STA          558           185         996         231              
8    GH           PRO          548           696         698         895               
9    AB           PRO          148           254         318         229                                                                              
10                                                                                
11    TOAL PER COMPANY PER DEPARTAMENT PER YEAR:            
12    AB PRO =
```

Comment: Is this just a sample; will there be more rows where you have the same company and department appearing more than once?

Comment: yes same company and department appears on more than one row

Comment: I see that tospig has given you a working solution but just FYI your formula fails because SUMPRODUCT needs to be fed ranges or arrays of the same size. If the sum range has multiple columns (and the criteria ranges are single columns) then you need to multiply all criteria with sum range, as per tospig's answer because then the matrix multiplication is done first and SUMPRODUCT is fed only one range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asusming that in Row 12, Col A = AB, and Row 12, Col B == PRO, then:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A9=A12)*(B2:B9=B12) *C2:F9)
```

Example:

[image: Sumproduct]